# Change the template inheritance hierarchy

Tags: theme, template, magento-1

Is there a way to change the template/skin inheritance hierarchy?

Currently you can have:

- custompackage/customtheme

  - custompackage/default

    - base/default

Is there a way or a module that would allow more control so you could do (for example):

- custompackage/customtheme1

  - custompackage/customtheme2

    - custompackage/default

      - base/default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look at Design Fallback from AOE.

http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/custom-design-fallbacks-in-magento.html